# Cannot run kubenetes deployments

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, kubernetes

I configuring kubernetes to have 3 images (my API, Elastic Search and Kibana)

Here is my `deployment.yml` file

```
 apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tooseeweb-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tooseeweb-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tooseeweb-pod
    spec: 
      containers:
      - name: tooseewebcontainer
        image: tooseewebcontainer:v1
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
      - name: kibana
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.2.4
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5601
```

When I run `kubectl get deployments` I see this

[image]

It's stuck on 0/1 ready. I try to reboot docker, etc. It not helps. How I can fix this?

**UPDATE**

I run `kubectl describe pod` and have this error

```
Warning  FailedScheduling  19s   default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu.
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: try describing the pods, and when you do kubectl get pods, you will get number of ready containers out of 3, try checking logs for those, may help

Comment: How I need to describe pods?@TusharMahajan

Comment: I mean, kubectl describe pod

Comment: Got this error `Warning  FailedScheduling  19s   default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu.` @TusharMahajan

Comment: You should probably split this into three separate deployments.  (What should happen if you take this existing deployment spec and set `replicas: 3`?)  That would also help you by letting you focus on (hopefully) the one part that's not starting up.

Answer (score 3):

Remove these resource limits in every pods.

```
resources:
   limits:
      memory: "128Mi"
      cpu: "500m"
```

If you want to limit the resources do it later after applying once the deployment successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are having trouble scheduling a pod. Kubernetes error message: `0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu`, means you dont have enough resources to run your pod.

Every one of your containers is requesting 0.5 of a cpu core so a whole pod needs 1.5 cpu cores to run. Kubernetes is unable to find a node with spare 1.5 cpu cores so it fails to schedule. If you want to run it you either need to lower your limits/requests of add more resources to your node.

I also noticed that you are putting all containers in the same pod and it's not a good practice. Whenever you can put every container in separate pod. This will also allow for better load spread among nodes. Put several containers in the same pod only if these have to go together and there is no other way.

Also notice that elasticsearch is a java application so limiting its memory to 128Mi will likely cause frequent restart and this is very undesirable behavior for a database.

Comment: put every container in separate pod

you mean make different files for different containers?

Comment: You seem not to be familiar with concept of a pod. Take a look at [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/)

Comment: okay, I read it, but I still not understand, how I need to correctly write `deployment.yml` file to deploy API, Elastic and Kibana

Answer (score 0):

Analysis:

- It depends on the pods that are already scheduled in the nodes.
- Kubernetes scheduler keeps track of the resources in the nodes and the pods scheduled in each of these nodes
- When scheduling a new pod, scheduler tries to identify a node where the pod can be scheduled
- If it could not find a node with the necessary resources requested by the pod, the scheduler will fail to schedule the pod and the pod would be stuck in Pending state

Solutions:

1. Reduce the resources allocated to existing pods / delete the unnecessary pods
2. Increase the resources available in the worker nodes